# TypeScript API factory.updateSourceFile, how to set the "pos" and "end" members of new statements (and their sub-nodes)?

Tags: typescript, transform, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm updating a sourceFile in a transform -

```
export function transformBefore(
  absTsconfigPath: string
): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> | ts.CustomTransformerFactory {
  return (ctx) => (sf) => {
    const add:ts.Statement[]=[];
    if (...){
      add.push(...createSomeSyntheticStatements(ctx.factory))
    }
    if (!add.length) return sf;
    const flags:ts.NodeFlags = sf.flags;
    const sf1 = ctx.factory.updateSourceFile(
      sf,ctx.factory.createNodeArray([...add,...sf.statements]));
    ts.setSourceMapRange(sf1, 
      ts.getSourceMapRange(sf)); // no effect on pos,end of added nodes
    const sf3 = visitorWalk(sf1,ctx); // no effect on pos,end of added nodes
    return sf3;
  }
```

It looks very much like the 2017 suggestion by Typescript's @weswigham [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18369#issuecomment-329852888).

Looking in the debugger I can see the new nodes at the start `sf3` all have `pos` and `end` members equal to `-1`.

I guess that shouldn't necessarily be a problem, but later, in an *after* transform working on the same file, a call to `node.getText()` results in an exception deep in Typescript.  Debugging the exception I can see the `pos` and `end` members are still `-1`, and on such a statement the exception occurs.

When running the after-transform without the before-transform, there is no exception.

I have a hunch there should be a way to update the `pos` and `end` member but I don't know it.  None of these threee did it:

- `ctx.factory.createNodeArray`
- `ts.setSourceMapRange` (hoping for side effect)
- a plain visitor walk calling `ts.forEachChild` recursively also had no (side) effect.

How can the `pos` and `end` members be updated?

(In the meantime, a workaround to avoid a crash in the later *after* transform is to access `node.text` instead of `node.getText()`, because `node.text` has the correct local value, while `node.getText()`appears to rely on `pos` and `end` to access the source files full text, which is out of sync.)

---

UPDATE:

I tried a different approach by updating the source file
using a different function `ts.updateSourceFile`, instead of
`ctx.factory.updateSourceFile` -

```
    const oldText = sf.getFullText();
    const newText = addedText + oldText;
    // The function checkChangeRange in typescript.js code-documents the specs for TextChangeRange and newText 
    const textChangeRange:ts.TextChangeRange = {newLength:addedText.length,span:{start:0,length:0}};
    const updatedSf = ts.updateSourceFile(sf,newText,textChangeRange,true);
    return updatedSf;
```

The debugger showed that `pos` and `end` were correctly set.
However, following that "success", typescript continued to perform it's **own** *before* transforms on the resulting source file, but it crashed when trying to access symbol data.  Perhaps this is because the new source file has not been type-checked, so there is no symbol data.